# Similarity measure for documents based on controlled vocabularies

Tags: python, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have a list of controlled vocabularies, e.g., term1, term2, termN.. A document may have one or more controlled vocabularies, but each vocabulary may only occurs once for each documents.

Let say the total controlled vocabularies are Term1, Term2, Term3, Term4, Term5, Term6.

1. Doc 1 (4 terms) : term1, term2, term5, term6
2. Doc 2 (2 terms) : term2, term5

Option1:
The Jaccard approach looks at the two data sets and finds the incident where both values are equal to 1. Therefore, I may convert the existence of a controlled term (term 1-6) for a document into binary vector 1,0. Then, compute the similarity based on Jaccard (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard.html)

- Doc1:{1,1,0,0,1,1}
- Doc2:{0,1,0,0,1,0}

Option 2 - use cosine similarity based on tf-idf as in http://brandonrose.org/clustering

Among these options (or perhaps other similarity measures), which measure is suitable to compute similarity between documents based on controlled vocabularies? I am new to data mining, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It wont let me leave a comment so I will leave an answer. I do something similar but in R, and find this helpful

```
http://text2vec.org/similarity.html#cosine_similarity
```

I do not know if there is a "right answer". I would try the different approaches and see which yields the answer most similar to a human's judgment. I think "Euclidean distance" may be best, but I don't know if that is available to you. I